# Update individual DataTable cells without re-rendering entire table

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a DataTable which I want to update with stock market prices (using the interval callback). The table is quite large, so I don’t want to re-render the entire table every time a single price changes. Is it possible to update just the cell containing the particular stock price which has changed? Basically, I want the price cells updating quickly and smoothly without everything else reloading. Is this possible using regular Dash components, or would I need to create my own table using React and handle the price updates on the React side? Any ideas welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTable component provides pagination precisely for the purpose of not having to render all the data on the screen, which by default is enabled and set to 250 rows per page.

> **[Pagination](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference)** is used to improve performance: instead of rendering all of
> the rows at once (which can be expensive), we only display a subset of
> them. With pagination, we can either page through data that exists in
> the table (e.g. page through 10,000 rows in data 100 rows at a time)
> or we can update the data on-the-fly with callbacks when the user
> clicks on the "Previous" or "Next" buttons. These modes can be toggled
> with the `page_action` parameter.

The best option imho is to take advantage of that and let the frontend do the work accordingly. The plus is that, when fetching stock market prices there could only be from zero to 250 (or <page_size>) rows to update on the screen, so in most cases (with a reasonable page size) it guarantees quick and smooth transitions.

The parameters are :

- `page_action` (default: 'native')
- `page_size` (default: 250)
- `page_current` (default: 0)
- `page_count` (optional)

---

Another idea (which does not exclude to use pagination) would be to make the interval callback set data updates to a [dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) component instead of updating the table directly. Data from the store can then be read clientside which allows to handle cell updates manually using javascript.

For example, sending current time as data :

```python
from datetime import datetime as dt

@app.callback(
    Output('store-id', 'data'),
    Input('interval-id', 'n_intervals')
)
def refresh_data(n_intervals):
    data = {'time': dt.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}
    return data
```

Then you can also register a [clientside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) to read these data from the client and do the updates when triggered :

```python
app.clientside_callback(
    '''
    function(data) {
        // data is a JSON object. 
        console.log("callback receives", data);

        // Here you can either update the Output component the 
        // Dash way (<output> is the DataTable component id) :
        // return data;

        // Or if you need more freedom, you would use a dummy output 
        // (all Dash callbacks must have at least one output) and 
        // tell Dash to not update it, for example : 
        updateTable(data);
        return window.dash_clientside.no_update;
    }
    ''',
    Output('<output>', '<property>'),
    [Input('store-id', 'data')]
)
```

Also depending on the `storage_type` : for `local` and `session` you can always use `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` to get the data as a JSON *string*, eg.

```js
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store-id'));
```

With `storage_type='memory'` it seems there is no way to get the data outside of a client side callback (though I haven't searched further).

Comment: great info- thanks! Pagination isn't actually suitable since we'll need to see all rows (with a vertical scroll) however the dcc.Store solution sounds promising. FYI I've switched from DataTable to AG-Grid using my own basic React wrapper based on the boilerplate template. Could you tell me how I can access the data in dcc.Store from the React JS code? If I can do that then it will be easy to just update the appropriate cells using React JS. Is there a way to just "grab" it from browser memory or would I need to define a React property and send from Dash it via callback or other?

Comment: @TokyoD Yep sure, you can grab data after each update using a Dash client side callback or a handler you register directly from the js code, and if using 'local' or 'session' storage, data are stored in the corresponding (global) object. I edited the answer to provide more details on that.

Comment: Apologies for tardy response - kept getting distracted. This is a fantastic solution and exactly what I was looking for! Returning an Output isn't an option as that re-renders the entire table. By overriding the return and calling updateTable() directly, the market data updates are very fast and smooth. FYI, to get a reference to the grid in the callback I added "window.agGrid=this;" in the componentDidMount() function in React and then called "window.agGrid.updateTable(data);" in the callback. You might want to add this to your solution above, for completeness. Thanks a lot!